# Плагин для Ckeditor и использованием ajax

Tags: ckeditor

Здравствуйте.
Надеюсь, что кто-то из вас работал с этим редактором.
Хотелось бы написать плагин для добавления ссылки на профиль пользователя. То есть ввёл ник, ajax'ом пробежался по базе данных, нашёл пользователей подходящих, вывел список, тыкнул нужного, в редактор добавилась ссылка.
Проблема у меня вот какая: как добавить кнопку в диалоговое окно, и повесить на неё обработчик события?
UPD: это решил, **теперь как-то нужно запросить аяксом результаты и запихнуть их в селект**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следуя по [простому гайду](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1) можно прийти к вот такому коду:

структура:

```
-plugins
|-example
-|-dialogs
--|-example.js
-|-plugin.js
```

Файл `plugin.js` содержит:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'example', {
    init: function( editor ) {
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Example', {
            label: 'Insert user',
            command: 'exampleDialog',
        });

        CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'exampleDialog', this.path + 'dialogs/example.js' );
        editor.addCommand( 'exampleDialog', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'exampleDialog' ) );
    }
});
```

Файл `example.js` содержит:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add("exampleDialog",function(editor){

    var select;
    var user='';

    return {
        title:'Добавить пользователя',
        minWidth:390,
        minHeight:230,
        contents:[{
            elements:[{
                type: 'text',
                id: 'ajax',
                label: 'Поиск пользователя',
                onChange: function( api ) {
                    // Load data asynchronously.
                    CKEDITOR.ajax.load('/?user=' + this.getValue(), function( data ) {
                        var users = JSON.parse(data);

                        for(var foo in users) {
                            select.add(users[foo]);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },{
                type: 'select',
                id: 'ajax_select',
                label: 'Найденные пользватели',
                items: [''],
                onChange: function( api ) {
                    user = this.getValue();
                },
                onLoad: function() {
                    select = this;
                }
            }]
        }],
        onOk: function() {
            var link = editor.document.createElement( 'a' );
            link.setAttribute('url', '/users/' + user);
            link.setText('комментарий к: ' + user);

            editor.insertElement( link );
        }
    }
});
```

Дерзайте! На забудьте собрать `ckeditor` так, чтобы был модуль `ajax`.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек, выручили! Кстати вроде бы не в первый раз.